# ionic4 how to set individual click event with ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngfor

I have a ngFor that show cards. When I click in any of those cards, I want to display the complete information of the card that I clicked

I tried this:

```js
private showDetailCard = false;
expandCard() {
   this.showDetailCard = !this.showDetailCard;
}
```

but when I click in one of those, all of them open.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div (click)="expandCard()" *ngFor="let key of cars">
   <!-- basic infomation -->
</div>

<div [@expandCard] *ngIf="showDetailCard">
   <!-- the rest of information -->
</div>
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution :

```html
<div *ngFor="let key of cars">
   <div (click)="expandCard(key.carId.value)">
      <!-- basic infomation -->
   </div>
</div>

<div [@expandCard] *ngIf="showDetailCard[key.carId.value]">
   <!-- the rest of information -->
</div>
```

ts:

```js
  private showDetailCard: any = {};
  expandCard(id) {
    if (this.showDetailCard[id] !== undefined) {
      this.showDetailCard[id] = !this.showDetailCard[id];
    } else {
      this.showDetailCard[id] = true;
    }
  }
```